# Java Text Adventure - How do you make choices for the user?

Tags: java

I am new to this forum, and coding in general. I decided to teach myself Java as my first programming language. I ordered a book called "Head First Java" the other day, and hopefully when I get it I will be able to teach myself a lot more efficiently. Anyways, I thought that I would try to create a game to help me learn Java (since my goal is to learn programming in order to build my own video games). I started a text adventure game today.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){

    // Introduction
    System.out.println("The year is 2507...");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Years have passed since the war.");
    System.out.println("The people lucky enough to survive the invasion migrated\nto the newly discovered planet Rothgar in an attempt to start a new life.");
    System.out.println("Will you survive on this new world, or will the human race fall into extinction? \n");

    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Press Enter to continue..");
    keyIn.nextLine();

    // Main Menu
    System.out.println("                                               Main Menu");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Enter one of the following options:\n");
    System.out.println("'Start' to begin.\n"); 
    System.out.println("'Exit' to quit the game.\n");
    System.out.println("'Instructions' to learn how to play.\n");
    System.out.println("'Credits' to learn more about the game.\n");


    }



}
```

I am sorry if my coding is ugly or not as efficient as possible, but like I said, I am trying to teach myself. Now, my question is this: How do I branch off of these four options? When the user inputs one of them, I would like my program to go to the appropriate part of the code (which I haven't written  yet). For example, if the user Enters "Credits", I want the output to be the credits of my game, and then I need the program to go back to the main menu, possibly after the user presses 'Enter' again. If the player does not input any of those four choices from the main menu, I would like my program to say "You don't follow directions very well, do you? Lets try this again."

I hope that I am clearly asking my question. All help is appreciated! I just started learning programming Java a few days ago and I am obviously still a newbie, but I plan on releasing my own games eventually as an indie game developer! :)

Comment: Keep reading your books and you'll learn the answers. This is really a very broad "how to write a program" question.

Comment: You're going to have to learn more about methods, classes, OOPs (object oriented programming) and objects, to essentially move to the next level of programming to solve this. Keep reading in your book and/or tutorial, and don't give up.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really looking for is the name for this.  It's called a `text menu`.  Search `java text menu` and you'll find plenty of examples.

Here are a few:

> 1. [Switch operated text menu](http://www.javaforstudents.co.uk/Code_snippets/Switch-operated_text_menu)
> 2. [Text based menu in java](http://chronicles.blog.ryanrampersad.com/2011/03/text-based-menu-in-java/)

There are more advanced ways to do this of course but this is a good place to start.